# How to make a PCB

Tags: pcb

I never made a PCB before, just breadboarding.

And now I have a very simple circuit, but I'm wondering what is the most practical way to convert it to a PCB.

Circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feBOFT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to use a small PCB board, 2x8cm like this:

[image]
I think the following is something that should work:

**TOP**

```
           A  B  C  D  E  F  
           o  o  o  o  o  o  

 V1 VCC X--o  o  o  o  o  o  

           o  <Res 960->  D  
                          1 
           o  o CH1 SW1_  _  

 V1 GND X--o  o  o  o  o  o  

           o  o  o  o  o  o
```

**BOTTOM**

```
           A  B  C  D  E  F  
           o  o  o  o  o  o  

 V1 VCC X--o--o  o  o  o  o  
           |                   
REL VCC x--o  X  o  o  X  X  

REL GND x--o  o  X--X  X--X  
           |                    
V1 GND  x--o  o  o  o  o  o  

           o  o  o  o  o  o
```

My questions:

- The relay has 3 pins which are spread (two on the left, CH1 in the middle), is it a good practice to keep them together (but at the cost of more soldering or not)?
- The Relay CH1 and Switch wires are in the middle of the board (part).... is this 'good practice' or better to always keep them at the side (but again at the cost of more soldering?)

Comment: PCB = Printed Circuit Board. PCB Board= Printed Circuit Board Board.  This message brought to you by the department of redundancies department.

Comment: @JRE Forgive my redundancy :-)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73818/discussion-on-question-by-michel-keijzers-how-to-make-a-pcb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The board you show is basically just something to hold your components in place. Works the same as your breadboard except with solder to make the connections. Electrically the placement of parts is rather irrelevant. So choose a configuration that is easy to use. For example if you put the LED directly next to the button then you will likely cover the LED while operating the button and can't see it. If you put the button right next to the relay it might be hard to reach, better to put it some distance from the relay so it is clear all around.

There is also another variant called a [Stripboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripboard) that has all holes in one direction connected. You then cut (a 3mm drill nicely does that) the strip where you don't want a connection. With this kind of board you can often place your parts such that you don't need any or far fewer wires.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Actually, the switch is I mentioned is more like a placeholder for two wires that go to a wire which is half yard away :-)

Comment: I will check into the stripboard, I want to finish it by Thursday so now it's too late to order stripboard, but maybe for next time I will use it. I'm not afraid of soldering, just that I don't know if there are some kind of standards. Although it's a hobby project, I try to learn from it.

Comment: Found it (and ordered), it's also called veroboard (just for others to know).